# AOT (Ahead-of-Time Compilation) For Ionic 2/3 Mobile Browsers

Tags: angular, ionic2, iot

I was looking for the AOT implementation at https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler and there is good documentation around.

How do we can achieve AOT using IONIC CLI for Mobile browser apps?

Comment: As far as I'm aware aot has been the default since beta 11 source: [this blog post](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-2-beta-11/)

Comment: My question is for Mobile Browsers apps, it is not specific to Android(APK) or Ios (IOS) or hybrid apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone needs to do AOT build ionic for mobile browser following command work fine -

```
npm run build --prod --aot
```

Answer (score 2):

As said by @0mpurdy it's by default aot compiled, but you can always ensure that it's compiling AOT by using `--aot` flag when building your app. This flag can be used since `app-scripts` 0.0.47 version.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. 
My question is for Mobile Browsers apps, it is not specific to Android (APK) or Ios (IOS) or hybrid.

Comment: @Kanchan [this forum post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/aot-compilation-is-not-obvious-for-new-users/87114) suggests that perhaps `npm run build --aot` is what you're looking for

Comment: @Kanchan if you're using the browser platform (`ionic platform add browser`) you can use all flags available in app-scripts. Or as sugested by 0mpurdy do a `npm run build --aot`.

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel. 

I have found the following command working perfectly for me.

     npm run build --prod --aot

Comment: @Kanchan you're welcome :D glad it worked. Can you mark my answer as correct? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielBarreto, Done!

Answer (score 1):

When **ionic cordova run android --aot** this command is not working follow this things.

> If you have more then one page remove all page **module.ts** file then remove IonicPage() inside  **.ts** file.

I hope It may help you.